# Application Insights Join/Combine Columns Into A Single Column

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have an application insights query.  And in this query I want to join/combine several columns into a single column for display how can this be accomplished.

I want to combine ip, city, state, country.

```
customEvents
| where timestamp >= ago(7d)
| where (itemType == 'customEvent')
| where name == "Signin"
| project timestamp, customDimensions.appusername,   client_IP,client_City,client_StateOrProvince, client_CountryOrRegion 
| order by timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 6):

`strcat` is your friend, with whatever strings you want as separators (i just use spaces in the example):

```
| project timestamp, customDimensions.appusername, 
  strcat(client_IP," ",client_City," ",client_StateOrProvince," ", client_CountryOrRegion)
```

also, the `| where (itemType == 'customEvent')` in your query is unnecessary, as everything in the `customEvents` table is already a `customEvent`.  you only need a filter like that on `itemType` if you join multiple tables somehow (like `union requests, customEvents` or a `join` somewhere in your query that references multiple tables)